# xcode 9 crash when open storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

XCode 9 GM Candidate 1 is currently crashing when opening a storyboard.

ProductBuildVersion: 9A235

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Could not find class named UIImage
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Replacement view is installing: <IBStoryboardCanvasViewController: 0x7fdf6d7f7d70 representing: (null)>
```

Comment: Im getting this as well.

Comment: it's a big problem... i can't work since several days D:

Comment: My only work around has been to do the work in XCode 8, and build with XCode 9.

Comment: it's incredible... have you any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: i've finally found a solution. 

-i've opened my project with xcode 8
-i've deleted one view controller per times and tried to open in xcode 9
- so when in xcode 9 stopped crash, i understand wich viewcontroller give the problem
-i've deletad an image from my imageview and now the project don't crash

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Xcode 9. It's not crashing, but freezing everytime. I have to force quit Xcode.

Comment: Also see DocPllana's solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46808117/2301213 . Fixed the crashes on mine (w xcode 9.1) without any code changes

Answer (score 23):

For me it was crashing on opening any storyboard or xib in my app. I have created a new single view app project, opened its storyboard without a problem, reopened my own project - and it started opening storyboards and xibs as usual. Probably a caching issue of some sort..

Here are the details of a crash I was experiencing:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Sending _openAs: to <IDEDocumentController: 0x7f944580a970> from <NSMenuItem: 0x7f94249528d0 Interface Builder - Storyboard>
ProductBuildVersion: 9A235
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-13196/InterfaceBuilderKit/IssueProvider/IBIssueProvider.m:72
Details:  castedInstance should be an instance inheriting from IBDocument, but it is IDEPegasusSourceEditor.SourceCodeDocument
Object:   <IBIssueProvider: 0x7f94366a73d0>
Method:   -updatedIssuesForDocument:
```

Another crash that I have experienced, and that got fixed the same way:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Sending openClickedNavigableItemAction: to <IDEStructureNavigator: 0x7ff718acde20 representing: <DVTExtension 0x7ff70acf22e0: Structure Navigator (Xcode.IDEKit.Navigator.Structure) v0.1 from com.apple.dt.IDEKit>> from <IDENavigatorOutlineView: 0x7ff7169ba340>
ProductBuildVersion: 9A235
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-13247/IDEKit/Editor/IDEEditorContext.m:1935
Details:  Unexpected document in IDEDocumentController:<IBXIBDocument: 0x7ff6fb013a00>(  0   -[IDEEditorDocument init] (in IDEKit)
```

Comment: Where can you find the crash logs for xcode? I can't find any answer on how to do that.

Comment: @thibautnoah, you can find them in Console.app in "User Reports" section.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue, but in my case it was not solved by removing nil keys. As highlighted by Vlad Valentin, it was related to a `UITabBarViewController` I had in my Storyboard.

The issue, as stated in the error thrown in the Xcode crash report:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Could not find class named UIImage
```

related to a ***background image*** I had assigned to the `tabBar`. Once I removed the image from the Storyboard source code, I could then open Interface Builder again.

**Remove:**

```
<tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" backgroundImage="Tabbar background" id="W28-zg-YXA">
```

When I tried re-adding the image using Interface Builder, Xcode threw the same exception. I have resorted to loading the image programmatically. Hope this helps, and will save some people having to fully re-create their `UITabBarViewController`'s.

Comment: Removing the `backgroundImage` key and value, did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly the issue for me also. Thank you VERY much for figuring this out.  As you stated.. just remove the backgroundImage for your TabBar element in the TabbarController.  AND you can NOT set in the interface builder at all.  Must be done from code currently.

Comment: Removing the backgroundImage="tabBar" works for me! Thanks!

Comment: oddly enough, i removed this as suggested but my app still would not run without error. so i added ios 11 new safe Area Layout guide in all my scenes. Then added this line back in and it worked! resolved all my issue.

Answer (score 15):

I'm getting a similar issue. In my case, I've found that it consistently crashes when opening via the file explorer, whereas opening via Open Quickly (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) does not cause XCode to crash.

Comment: SUPER weird that this trick works. lol...that's some bug right there. Thanks!

Comment: Life saver! Was unable to open xib, storyboard, launchscreen files ;/ Thanks for sharing)

Comment: Works for me too!

Comment: Worked for me too, did the Open Quickly once, and then it starts working for all the other storyboards

Answer (score 8):

The issue is a nil key tag (at least for my case)

`<nil key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>`

or more generally

`<nil key="<generic_name>"/>`

That has its counterpart

`<simulatedToolbarMetrics key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>`

or more generally

`<<generic_name> key="generic_name"/>`

Removing all of them solves the issue.

1. Open the storyboard as *Source Code*
2. Search and remove: `<nil key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>` or any `<nil key="<generic_name>"/>`(replace `<generic_name>` with your particular tag name)
3. Search and remove their counter part: `<simulatedToolbarMetrics key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>` or any `<< generic_name > key="generic_name"/>` (replace `<generic_name>` with your particular tag name)
4. Save and open your storyboard normally
5. Enjoy

EDIT:

This tags seems to be related and are in the *Storyboard Source Code* of `UITabBarController`s however their counterparts are scattered around `UIViewControllers` connected to the `UITabBarController`. Can be one, two or more levels below.

Comment: This seems to work for me right now. I had a couple of <nil key="textColor"> and <nil key="highlightedColor"> and possible a few more. Just got rid of that and storyboard loads now.

Comment: I have replaced `<nil key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>` and `<nil key="highlightedColor">`. Any idea what I should use for `<nil name="viewControllers"/>`?

Comment: This `<nil name="viewControllers"/>` is inside of <navigationController>

Comment: Sry for my late response @Uma, I'm not sure but you can try opening the storyboard without deleting this particular key name.

Comment: remove all <nil .. > also <nil name="viewControllers"/> it works for me

Comment: Hi @victor.vasilica Thanks for your reply, It Keeps crashing.

Comment: @Nazir I get error "The document "Main.storyboard" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)"

Comment: @Nazir Still crashes when I try to open it crashes

Comment: @Uma make sure you had found all `<nil ...>` objects ... I also was getting error, after I found and removed all nil objects in my case they were `"color"` and `"highlighted"` the problem was solved

Comment: @Uma if you deleted *all* `<nil ... >` tags but the storyboard crashes try cleaning the project, removing the derived data, restarting XCode and then checking again for `<nil ...>` tags and opening the storyboard normally.

Comment: victor.vasilica and @Nazir I had only three types of <nil ..> tags. highlightedColor, viewcontrollers and simulatedBottomBarMetrics. I removed them all, cleaned the project, removed derived data, restarted xcode and checked again for <nil..>. None found. Tried to open SB normally and it crashes again

Comment: Now I get a different log in xcode crash report - UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Could not find class named UIImage
Peza's answer now. Thank you both very much for your help. I appreciate it @Nazir and victor.vasilica

Comment: Any time @Uma, glad you found a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for my case. It was crashing from the UITabBarViewController.

1. Open the storyboard as source code
2. Search for your UITabBarViewController
3. Remove the tab bar
4. Open storybard as Interface builder
5. Create new tab bar and connect the root view controllers you need

As Michele Schillaci said, you can try to remove some view controller and check if that solved the problem.

Comment: 3. Remove the tab bar < does this mean to remove the whole of tabBarController tag?

Comment: For me, the problem was the connections, thats why the storyboard crashed. But I had to add a new tab bar controller to be able to connect new connections.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug with tab bars containing system tab bar items. The Xcode 9.1 release notes acknowledge this, and suggest a workaround:

> ## Interface Builder
>
> A UITabBarItem configured as a system item in a storyboard or xib causes a build failure. (34197132)
>
> **Workaround**: Configure as a custom item in Interface Builder, then reset the tab bar item to the desired system item in the `awakeFromNib` method of the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `<nil key ="....">` but it didn't work. So i tried that (From @Vlad Valentin):

1. Open the storyboard as source code.
2. Search for `tabBarController`

   ```
    <scene sceneID="RIF-kY-Kwk">
       <objects>
           <tabBarController storyboardIdentifier="mainViewController" id="p5V-Jj-erc" customClass="MainViewController" customModule="yourModule" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
               <tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="kWD-Cd-EAU">
                   <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="49"/>
                   <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                   <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
               </tabBar>
               <connections>
                   <segue destination="FQU-DF-g8S" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="wf7-sS-3aP"/>
                   <segue destination="cVl-bj-mqD" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="A5l-iP-1pv"/>
                   <segue destination="yE9-HB-Hqo" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="U4m-N7-DeC"/>
                   <segue destination="PmG-7U-DMm" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="u4J-Y7-Z51"/>
               </connections>
           </tabBarController>
           <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="APY-5z-hrA" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
       </objects>
       <point key="canvasLocation" x="-3126" y="1236"/>
   </scene>
   ```
3. `storyboardIdentifier="mainViewController"`, `customClass="MainViewController"` and `<connections>..</connections>` are important for you. Copy and paste it.
4. Remove `scene`.
5. Now you can open storyboard with Interface Builder.
6. Add Tab Bar Controller (Drag Drop and remove child view controller.)
7. Go Stroyboard source code and paste `storyboardIdentifier`, `customClass` and `connections`.

Comment: have you removed their counterparts: `<<key_name> key="<key_name>">` ?

Comment: Yes. I have 5 storyboards in my project and i checked all of them have nil tag. But just one, has Tab Bar Controller,  was not opening.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix:

Just put `insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO"` on `<tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ytw-4N-0RV">` and remove all `<nil key ="....">` from your storyboard source code.

E.g:

```
<tabBarController id="mhN-Gc-eXK" sceneMemberID="viewController" restorationIdentifier="tabbar" storyboardIdentifier="tabbar" customClass="TabbarMainViewController">
    <tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="ytw-4N-0RV">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="49"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too.
Crash(rainbow ball rotating) when I click my storyboard file in Xcode of my working project. It's happened even if I create a new single view project.

For me, I restart my Mac Book to be a workaround solution.

Hope this can fix ur problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the previously installed versions of XCode were the root of the problem. I thought I only had one version installed but upon right-clicking an XCode project file, I saw that under 'Open With..', there were tons of versions. There were old beta versions of XCode 9, as well as various versions of the stable release and even XCode 8.

None of these versions could be found in my mac's Applications directory, so I realized that they were dormant in the Downloads directory. What I did was delete all of them and boom, storyboard not freezing XCode 9.3 anymore.

Comment: Same problem, same fix, except with Xcode 9.3 breaking Xcode 10.2. Moved 9.3 from Downloads to Trash and everything's fine now. Weird!

Comment: Same problem fixed. I'm using Xcode 11 Beta 5. Removed all previous versions and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced this

```
<tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" translucent="NO" backgroundImage="background_tabbar" selectionIndicatorImage="background_tabbar_item" id="Z9r-yE-1Zs">
```

on that

```
<tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Z9r-yE-1Zs">
```

and Xcode doesn't crash anymore when I try to open the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

So I had an issue whereby as soon as I opened a storyboard in XCode 9 the file was modified (not unusual for XCode) - but then whenever I ran the app with Exception breakpoints enabled it crashed. Hitting continue from the debugger allowed the app to then run normally.

Looking at what XCode has modified in the storyboard file, it turned that at the top of the file, before the 'scenes' xml element, it was adding:

```
<customFonts key="customFonts">
    <array key="GillSans.ttc">
        <string>GillSans</string>
        <string>GillSans-Light</string>
    </array>
</customFonts>
```

Removing this stopped the weird crash issue, but modifying the storyboard keeps adding the code back in. It appears the solution would be to remove all custom fonts from the storyboard and set them in code - or hope this is just a weird bug which will be fixed in a later XCode version.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue: a storyboard created in Xcode 8 would hang in Xcode 9. After taking my Storyboard apart by exporting the views one by one (using Editor / Refactor to Stoyboard - a feature I didn't know existed until I was struck by this issue) I found that two specific views were causing Xcode to hang.

In both these views, I had added more than one item to a UITabBar - a button on the left, a flexible space and a button on the right. If Xcode tried to display this, it would hang. If I quickly clicked to any other Storyboard once these "poisoned" views were seen, it would also hang.

The solution is therefore to open the project in Xcode 8, remove all but one item from the TabBar, delete any Derived Data folders, quit Xcode 8, load Xcode 9, do a Product / Clean, and if you're lucky, you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open another project's ".storyboard" and then go back to the project which is making Xcode crash!

I had this exact problem with Xcode 9.1 (9B55) on a project which was ok yesterday. Today when I tried to open any ".storyboard/.xib" file Xcode was crashing!

As some people suggested I removed all "`<nil key=...`" tag contents.
It worked but meanwhile I had opened another project's storyboard. Then I restored all my changes and it worked again.

This seems not caused by the "`<nil key=...`" tag contents but by some weird state in which Xcode becomes.