# Adding background image property to UITabBarController in storyboard crashes xCode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, xcode9

I've been trying to compile my app in xcode 9 but a lot of strange things have been happening causing me to find work arounds. One of them in particular is working with UITabBarController. it seems completely broken in xCode 9. i found a work around here [xcode 9 crash when open storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311398/xcode-9-crash-when-open-storyboard) . I completely recreated UI tab bar but now when i try to add an background image in the story board it crashes xcode 9, also tried in xcode 9 beta. crashes there was well. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 9A235
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Could not find class named UIImage
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Sending popUp: to <IBButtonComboBoxCell: 0x7f9d15fb92a0> from <IBButtonComboBox: 0x7f9d18549aa0>
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] (in Foundation)
  5   -[IBBinaryUnarchiver classForClassName:] (in IBFoundation)
  6   -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeClass] (in IBFoundation)
  7   -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] (in IBFoundation)
  8   -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObjectReferenceIfPossible] (in IBFoundation)
  9   -[NSDictionary(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) initWithBinaryUnarchiver:] (in IBFoundation)
 10   +[NSObject(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] (in IBFoundation)
 11   -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] (in IBFoundation)
 12   -[IBUIMetricRepresentation initWithBinaryUnarchiver:] (in IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation)
 13   +[NSObject(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] (in IBFoundation)
 14   -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] (in IBFoundation)
 15   -[IBUISimulatedTabBarControllerMetricChain initWithBinaryUnarchiver:] (in IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation)
 16   +[NSObject(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] (in IBFoundation)
 17   -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] (in IBFoundation)
 18   +[IBBinaryUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithDataArray:context:] (in IBFoundation)
 19   -[IBUISimulatedMetricChain copyWithPrecedingMetric:] (in IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation)
 20   -[IBUISimulatedMetricChainVerificationState rebuildSimplifiedChain] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 21   +[IBUISimulatedMetricChainValidator validatedMetricChain:forViewControllerWithLeafMetric:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 22   -[IBUIViewController(IBUIViewControllerIntegration) ibUpdateInheritedSimulatedMetrics:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 23   -[IBStoryboardMetricsInferrer recursivelyApplyMetricsInheritenceToController:visited:inheritanceSegues:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24   -[IBStoryboardMetricsInferrer recursivelyApplyMetricsInheritenceToController:visited:inheritanceSegues:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25   -[IBStoryboardMetricsInferrer rebuildInferredMetrics] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 26   -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 27   -[DVTDelayedInvocation invokeIfNeeded] (in DVTFoundation)
 28   -[DVTDelayedInvocation invoke] (in DVTFoundation)
 29   -[IBDocument sceneUpdateManager:marshallableObjectPackageForRootObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 30   -[IBSceneUpdateManager _updateScenes] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31   -[IBSceneUpdateManager _updateScenesIteratively] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 32   __48-[DVTDelayedInvocation initWithTarget:selector:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 33   -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 34   __NSFirePerformWithOrder (in Foundation)
 35   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 36   __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 37   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 38   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 39   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 40   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 41   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 42   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 43   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 44   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 45   -[NSComboBoxCell filterEvents:] (in AppKit)
 46   -[NSComboBoxCell popUp:] (in AppKit)
 47   _os_activity_initiate_impl (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 48   -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 49   __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 50   DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 51   -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 52   -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)
 53   __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 54   _os_activity_initiate_impl (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 55   -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
 56   -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
 57   __48-[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 58   _os_activity_initiate_impl (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 59   -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 60   -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 61   -[NSComboBoxCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 62   -[NSComboBox mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 63   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 64   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 65   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 66   -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 67   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 68   -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 69   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 70   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 71   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

Comment: I am getting same issue. Did you find solution ?

Comment: @gstream79 i ended up adding it programmatically. it doesn't crash when you do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added it programmatically