# XCode 9 is being crashed on opening all storyboard files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have tried following solutions to fix this issue

- removed derive data
- clean build
- create new storyboard file

Comment: i have seen all post but i could not fix the issue

Comment: What is your stack trace of the crash ?

Comment: @HaroonUrRasheed Why you accept the answer here then? Because it is the same solution as users provided in the post you are duplicating.

Comment: please read my comments on accepted answer

Comment: @HaroonUrRasheed Still do not see why you are duplicating the same question and moreover why you accepted something that is not even proper solution (based on you comment).

Answer (score 5):

- The solution for me was to remove user data in .xcodeproj and .xcworkspace.

Right click > Show package content > and remove xcuserdata FOLDER ONLY.

- Other way to fix this is to open that project with other xcode version( for ex. you are working in xcode 8.2, open with 8.3) and close all windows, quit xcode and open the project with xcode version you want.

Comment: Brilliant! Doing this sorted out this issue for me.