# I can't open the storyboard because of crash

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, storyboard, iso

I just have begin to study swift and installed Xcode9.4.1 today.
When I make new project and open the storyboard without any modification, xcode crash.
I couldn't find the solution for this problem. How to fix it?

I don't know which information is required to solve this problem.
If you need any information, then I give you what you want.

Thank for reading my question.

Comment: How much memory is available in your system?

Comment: My macbook pro has 8GB ram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode 9 crash when open storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311398/xcode-9-crash-when-open-storyboard)

Comment: maybe 5 to 6 GB? What  is the minimum memory required for xcode?

Comment: @Min That is not the problem, I am asking how much memory consuming your system. And much is remaining

Comment: why storyboard!! use `xib` or `code` or `mix` (xib and code) for ui

Comment: @Min: Please clean your DerivedData and quite your xcode and again open your xcode

Comment: @Jogendar Choudhary   I'm using 3.73GB and xcode consumed 160MB

Comment: @SPatel storyboard is not essential?

Comment: @Jogendar Choudhary I have done already several times

Comment: @Min: Check storyboard support which version of Xcode?

Comment: @Jogendar Choudhary xcode 9.4.1 that I installed with appstore

Comment: Close all projects, then open existing project, delete derived data and do clean build and build, it may solve your problem.

Comment: @Min no, is not essential but it convenient for beginner

Comment: @SPatel : oh I see, is there any stuff of learning xib for beginner?